# How do I extract the middle name from the full name?

Tags: java

My program is supposed to extract the middle name of a full name. I have another method and I can't call it properly in my main method. The code is working if it is in the main method, but it doesn't work in the other method; I assume the problem is when calling the method. I am using Eclipse.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MiddleNames {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    getMiddleName(" ");
    System.out.println();
  }

  public static String getMiddleName(String middleName) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your full name: ");
    String fullName = input.nextLine();
    int firstSpace = fullName.indexOf(" ");
    int lastSpace = fullName.lastIndexOf(" ");
    middleName = fullName.substring(firstSpace,lastSpace);
    return middleName;  
  } 
}
```

Comment: what means "it does not work"? do you get an error? do you get just nothing? - i mean, you never print the result of the method getMiddleName. so "nothing" would be what i'm expacting.

Comment: -1 You have already asked 7 related questions and all of them have been nicely answered by several users but you have not bothered to accept any of them! Make an effort and first read some basic Java tutorial/book.

Comment: can you specify what is problem you are facing and how you are trying to call your method??

Comment: I appologize for not being clear, well as the code is now it is not working like when you enter full name it does not print anythink, if the code is tin the main code it is working

Comment: @Kiril Have a look on my answer.

Comment: Come on -.- don't let stackoverflow do all of your homework....

Comment: How would you get my middle name when I use it where most people's first name would be. It's always a bad idea to make assumptions about names. One of my favorite authors is called "Charle de Lint".

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that in your java you should not be passing anything into the method. Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String middleName = getMiddleName();
    System.out.println(middleName);
}

public static String getMiddleName() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your full name: ");
    String fullName = input.nextLine();
    int firstSpace = fullName.indexOf(" ");
    int lastSpace = fullName.lastIndexOf(" ");
    String middleName = fullName.substring(firstSpace,lastSpace);
    return middleName;  
}
```

Actually, I would use `split` to extract the name parts:

```
String[] names = fullName.split(" ");
return names[1]; // fyi names[0] is the first name, names[2] is the last name
```

or simply:

```
return fullName.split(" ")[1];
```

Comment: when i compile it it get this error  "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method getMiddleName(String) in the type MiddleNames is not applicable for the arguments ()

 at MiddleNames.main(MiddleNames.java:4)"

Comment: Did you change `getMiddleName(" ");` to `getMiddleName();` in your main method and change your method to not have the String argument? I would copy-paste my code and try that.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that you copy-pasted all the code from the main method to a new method, instead of extraction the functionality itself.

Here's a start:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your full name: ");
    String fullName = input.nextLine();

    getMiddleName(" ");      <----- Here you should send your string instead of an empty string.
    System.out.println();    <----- You want to print the name returned by the methodcall from the previous line. This line will only print an empty line now.
}
public static String getMiddleName(String middleName) {    <----- The string you get is named "middleName" here
    int firstSpace = fullName.indexOf(" ");                <----- And here it's called fullName.
    int lastSpace = fullName.lastIndexOf(" ");             <----- Here too
    middleName = fullName.substring(firstSpace,lastSpace); <----- And here..
    return middleName;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you read a parameter if you don't use it ?
try  this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MiddleNames {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getMiddleName());
    }
        public static String getMiddleName()
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter your full name: ");
            String fullName = input.nextLine();
            int firstSpace = fullName.indexOf(" ");
            int lastSpace = fullName.lastIndexOf(" ");
            String middleName = fullName.substring(firstSpace,lastSpace);
            return middleName;  
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String yourMiddleName = getMiddleName(" ");
    System.out.println(yourMiddleName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting `static` on the definition of `getMiddleName` oblige you to use the method by a `static` way `MiddleNames.getMiddleName()` or to use the method in an other `static` method. It work for main because it is already a `static` method.

Solutions:

- Change to `static` your other method
- Remove `static` from the declaration of getMiddleName
- Call getMiddleName like this `MiddleNames.getMiddleName()`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you dont handle the case where there is only one space in the input. In that case firstSpace and lastSpace is the same and the result will be an emty string

Answer (score 0):

```
String fullName = "FirstName MiddleName LastName"; 
String[] s = fullName.split(" ");
    
// System.out.println("Get the length of the array middle position "+ s.length / 2);
    
String middleName = s[s.length/2];
System.out.println(middleName);
```